# PortAudio shows a device count of zero for both Asio and WDM-KS

Tags: c++, asio, portaudio

PortAudio is showing a deviceCount of 0 and a defaultOutputDevice of -1 for both the ASIO and Windows WDM-KS host APIs. I did successfully build PortAudio to include support for both ASIO and Windows WDM-KS and both options do show up when iterating over the available hosts. I have also verified that I do have ASIO4All installed. What am I doing wrong? I am running windows inside a virtual machine (vmware) on a Mac. Is that causing issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Luckily, I had a friend who had a project working using ASIO. He let me try running his code on my box and it was able to find the ASIO devices correctly. From there it was a matter of working backwards until I found the thing that was different between the 2 projects.

Both projects used a c# application to host a managed c++ assembly that made the calls into PortAudio. The issue ended up being that my projects `static void Main(string[] args)` didn't have an `[STAThread]` attribute. Once I added that, the ASIO devices started showing up. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious test would be to quickly install a host on the vm that supports ASIO. You can try Reaper http://www.reaper.fm/ as it is free to download and use while evaluating it.

If the 3rd party host software supports the device via asio4all, then you know that you have some error using port audio.

If the 3rd party audio host does not recognise the device either, then look into your asio4all setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. ASIO does work with other applications.